# PowerShell update Azure Service Principals Properties Tags

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli

Using PowerShell to update Service Principals IDs found here on Microsoft Docs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Service Principal -> Properties -> tags

How can I add custom tag to the Service Principal?

```
# Get all Service Principals

# az login

# az ad sp list --all


# Set Service Principal ID

$ServicePrincipalID = ""

# Show Service Principal Information

$ServicePrincipalData = az ad sp show --id $ServicePrincipalID
Write-Host $ServicePrincipalData


# Update Service Principal Properties Custom Tag

az rest --method PATCH --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$ServicePrincipalID --body '{\"tags\":[\"AssetID\"]}'
# az rest --method PATCH --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$ServicePrincipalID --body '{"tags":["AssetID","SubscriptionID"]}'



# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-update
# az ad sp update --id $ServicePrincipalID --set tags=["AssetID_<>"]
# az ad sp update --id $ServicePrincipalID --set 'tags=["AssetID_<>"]'


# Custom JSON Object input for tags property



$input = @"
{
  "tags": [
    "AssetID_<>",
    "SubscriptionID_<>"
  ],
}
"@

$jObject = $input | convertfrom-json

az ad sp update --id $ServicePrincipalID --set tags $jObject
```

Answer (score 1):

To update tags on service principals, call Microsoft Graph API [Update servicePrincipal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
$ az rest --method PATCH --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/52e3d1ac-48c1-4486-8ed6-ad99a74415a7 --body '{"tags":["mytag2_sp"]}'
$ az rest --method GET --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/52e3d1ac-48c1-4486-8ed6-ad99a74415a7

...
  "tags": [
    "mytag2_sp",
    "mytag1_app"
  ],
```